# Creation of contract pending

Tags: solidity, remix, binance-smart-chain

So I have tried to create my own token on Binance Smart Chain Network. For some reason in Remix my creation of contract is still pending while I looked on BSC and there it shows that transaction went successfully and contract is created. Does anyone knows why my creation in remix is still pending?

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
    
    contract Token {
        mapping(address => uint) public balances;
        mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
        uint public totalSupply = 1000000000 * 10 ** 18;
        string public name = "name";
        string public symbol = "nam";
        uint public decimals = 18;
        
        event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
        event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
        
        constructor() {
            balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        }
        
        function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
            return balances[owner];
        }
        
        function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
            require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
            balances[to] += value;
            balances[msg.sender] -= value;
           emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
            return true;
        }
        
        function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
            require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
            require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
            balances[to] += value;
            balances[from] -= value;
            emit Transfer(from, to, value);
            return true;   
        }
        
        function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
            allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
            emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
            return true;   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has similar issue in future. Basically token was created but Remix was not showing that I successfully transfered token into my wallet without doint anything specific